# How to format autocomplete suggestions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, autocomplete

for my current project I am using jquery autocomplete for a quicksearch with autosuggestions. In general it works fine. Though, I am havig trouble with formating. Below this link points to my example

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
    var  tagsAutocomplete = ["Schaufenster", "Schauspieler", "Schadenfreude"];
    $("#suche").autocomplete({
      appendTo:"#main1 arrowbox",
      minLength: 3,
      source: function(request, response) {
       var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term),"i");
       response($.grep(tagsAutocomplete,function(item){
        return matcher.test(item);
       }) );
      }
    });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.11.0/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="canvas">
   <section id="cont-right">
      <div class="systemDiv">
     <nav id="main">
      <ul>
       <li id="main1">
        <ul>
         <li>
          <div class="arrowbox">
           <div class="image-menu-item">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="ui-autocomplete-input" name="query" id="suche" maxlength="180" placeholder="Suchbegriff" tabindex="-1" type="text">
           </div>
          </div>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
    </div>
   </section>
  </div>
```

I tried to add "margin-bottom" or "margin-top" in different places. Nothing did help. The result list is always stick underneath the input field. I found some posts here in SO either, but the didn't could help.

Have someone an idea? Thanks.

Note: The three first letter "sch" will list all entries.

Comment: @Tushar The minimal complete and verifiable example can be found under `jsfiddle.net/reporter/8tmmw9b0/`if you add `https://`. The richtext editor does not accept links that points to jsfiddle (or I don't know how create appropiate jsfiddle links)

Comment: Check https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Together with a colleague I was able to find a solution for my problem.

By adding `ul.ui-autocomplete {top: <number of pixels>px !important;}` solved my problem.

The main reason is, that the css declaration in css file *jquery-ui.css* overrides all costumised values.